# Add subview of xib tableview cell (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a `tableview` and xib `tableviewcell`. i use the xib `tableviewcell` by adding subview. however it seems lost the function of                          `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

i want this custom `tableviewcell` inherit the normal `cell` in my `tableview`.
how to do that??

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var myTableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self

    myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 250, 400)//Optional for table size

    myTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myIdentifier")

    self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myIdentifier") as! MyTableViewCell
    myCell.myString1.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
    myCell.myString2.text = "String \(indexPath.row)"
    return myCell
}
```

}

Comment: maybe i shouldn't addsubview??

Comment: No, you definitely don't.

Comment: If you created the nib properly, and it inherits from UITableView cell, then that is all you need to do for it to have the basic functionality.

Comment: So didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called anymore? Your code looks pretty fine for the purpose. As long as `MyTableViewCell` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell` you`re good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to inherit from UITableViewController, and not UIViewController. As such:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableview.delegate = self
    self.tableview.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myIdentifier")
)
```

Comment: i don't get it. i am now having a tableview inside the viewcontroller

Comment: See my updated answer, you don't need to create a new tableview and add it as subview